# How to copy a preloaded Pandas Dataframe in Python from an online kernel system, to my main IDE on my Ubuntu System

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, kernel

I'm using an online website that has it's own kernel for practising manipulating dataframes, but occasionally the dataframe is preloaded into the kernel and all I can do is use commands like .head() .info() and all other dataframe oriented commands to manipulate it but I am unable to find a way to copy this dataframe in a way that allows me to use the contents of the dataframe on jupyter notebooks or other IDEs on my system.

I thought maybe I could save the dataframe as a CSV but alas I am unable to download files through the online kernel.

Any idea's as to how I can bypass this problem?

Comment: Can you download / upload files? Try df.to_pickle(‘my_df.pkl’) and pd.from_pickle(‘my_df.pkl’)

Comment: @skarchmit, Unfortunately not, Uploading and downloading files doesn't seem to work either. I was thinking maybe outputting a dataframe as a dictionary and then copying that dictionary but it just outputs the first and last parts because its a lot of data and just (etc's) the large middle portion.

Comment: Reading your data aside, how can your IDE give you your data?

Comment: @skarchmit I'm not sure what you mean by my IDE give me my data. I'm just using IDE to refer to the place I compile my python code on my main computer as opposed to the virtual system that is the online kernel. I also figured it out after some time, my answer is posted below.

Answer (score 1):

***Answering my own question after finding an answer.

The best way to do this if you can't download and upload files is to convert the columns of the dataframe into a list and then copy the output of those lists on to a seperate system, where you can then rezip the columns with each other and thereby recreate the dataframe for usage there.

```
    Temp = [79.0, 77.4, 76.4, 75.7]
```

(this list could theoretically have any number of values no matter how high)
this was converted from the dataframe within the kernel by doing

```
    print(df['Temperature (deg F)'].values.tolist())
```

and the lists can be recopied elsewhere and then converted back into a dataframe by using

```
    dataFrame = pd.DataFrame({'Temperature (deg F)': Temp})
```